# out of memory when trying to select data from oracle database and insert it into sqlite

Tags: java, oracle, sqlite, jar, out-of-memory

we get out of memory (the process go up and consumes %100 of ram) trying to select data and insert it into SQLite DB, the program written in java, and  the data are so big, we even made pagination for it, it selects 100000 rows and inserts it into SQLite database, to figure out the problem, we commented out all line from the code that insert the data, and we saw that consumption of ram stop's at %6

```
package dbex;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBEX {

    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.120.46:1521:db";
    String user = "dbuser";
    String password = "dbpass";

    ArrayList<Table> Tales = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBEX db = new DBEX();
        db.CreateDB();

    }

    public int CountRecords(String table) {
        int result = 0;

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            Connection getCountCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Statement CountSt = getCountCon.createStatement();
            ResultSet countRs = CountSt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM " + table);
            while (countRs.next()) {
                result = countRs.getInt("num");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
        return result;
    }

    public void dumpData() {

        try {
            int incrementRecord = 100000;
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            Table table = null;
            ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
            Connection getDataCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            getDataCon.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement dataSt = getDataCon.createStatement();
            dataSt.setFetchSize(incrementRecord);
            ResultSet dataRs = null;

            Connection LiteInsertCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + "DBEX" + ".db");
            LiteInsertCon.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement insertStatement = null;


            int numRecord = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < Tales.size(); i++) {

                table = Tales.get(i);
                String tableName = table.name;
                System.out.println("table::" + tableName);
                System.out.println("Dumping data from " + tableName);
                String InsertSQL = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " ( ";
                String vals = "VALUES (";
                String selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT b.*, ROWNUM RN FROM ( SELECT ";
                System.out.println("geting column name...");
                columns = table.Columns;
                for (int j = 0; j < columns.size(); j++) {

                    String columnName = columns.get(j);
                    if (j == 0) {
                        vals += " ? ";
                        InsertSQL += columnName + " ";
                        selectSQL += columnName + " ";
                    }else {
                        InsertSQL += " , " + columnName + " ";
                        vals += ", ? ";
                        selectSQL += " , " + columnName + " ";
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Number of column of table " + tableName + " is " + columns.size());

                vals += ")";
                InsertSQL += ")" + vals;
                selectSQL += "FROM " + tableName + " ORDER BY "+table.primary_key+" ASC ) b WHERE ROWNUM <= :TO ) WHERE RN > :FROM  ";
                System.out.println(selectSQL);
                System.out.println(InsertSQL);
                int parIndex = 0;
                String colName = null;
                String data = null;
                numRecord = CountRecords(tableName);

                int from = 0;
                int to = incrementRecord;

                if (to > numRecord) {
                    System.out.println("Table data is less than "+incrementRecord+" geting all data "+numRecord+" " );
                    dataRs = dataSt.executeQuery(selectSQL.replace(":TO", numRecord + "").replace(":FROM", "0"));

                    while (dataRs.next()) {
                        insertStatement = LiteInsertCon.prepareStatement(InsertSQL);
                        insertStatement.setFetchSize(incrementRecord);
                        for (; parIndex < columns.size(); parIndex++) {
                            colName = columns.get(parIndex);
                            data = dataRs.getString(colName);
                            if (data != null) {
                                insertStatement.setString(parIndex + 1, data);
                            } else {
                                insertStatement.setString(parIndex + 1, " ");
                            }
                            parIndex++;
                        }
                        parIndex = 0;
                        insertStatement.executeUpdate();
                        insertStatement = null;
                    }

                } else {
                    while (numRecord >= to) {
                        System.out.println("page "+(to/incrementRecord)+" of "+(numRecord/incrementRecord) ); 
                        dataRs = dataSt.executeQuery(selectSQL.replace(":TO", to + "").replace(":FROM", from+""));
                        while (dataRs.next()) {
                            insertStatement = LiteInsertCon.prepareStatement(InsertSQL);
                            insertStatement.setFetchSize(incrementRecord);
                            for (; parIndex < columns.size(); parIndex++) {
                                colName = columns.get(parIndex);
                                data = dataRs.getString(colName);
                                if (data != null) {
                                    insertStatement.setString(parIndex + 1, data);
                                } else {
                                    insertStatement.setString(parIndex + 1, " ");
                                }
                                parIndex++;
                            }
                            parIndex = 0;
                            insertStatement.executeUpdate();
                            insertStatement = null;
                        }
                        dataRs=null;
                        from = to;
                        to += incrementRecord;
                        System.gc();
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }

    }

    class Table {

        public String name;
        public String primary_key;
        ArrayList< String> Columns = new ArrayList<>();

        public Table(String name, String primary_key, ArrayList< String> Columns) {
            this.name = name;
            this.primary_key = primary_key;
            this.Columns = Columns;
        }
    }

    public void CreateDB() {



        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Oracle JDBC driver found");

            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

            Connection getTableCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Connection getColumnCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Connection getKeyCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            System.out.println("connected to database");
            Statement getTableSt = getTableCon.createStatement();

            PreparedStatement getColumnSt = getColumnCon.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM all_tab_cols WHERE table_name = ? ");

            PreparedStatement getKeySt = getKeyCon.prepareStatement("SELECT cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.position, cons.status, cons.owner FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols WHERE cols.table_name = ? AND cons.constraint_type = 'P' AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name AND cons.owner = cols.owner ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position");

            ResultSet getTableRs = getTableSt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM all_tables WHERE OWNER not in('SYS','OUTLN','SYSTEM')");

            ResultSet getColumnRs;
            ResultSet getKeyRs;


            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            System.out.println("Sqlite JDBC driver found");

            Connection LiteCreateTableCon = null;
            LiteCreateTableCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + "DBEX" + ".db");
            Statement statement = LiteCreateTableCon.createStatement();
            String keyName = "";

            while (getTableRs.next()) {

                String tableName = getTableRs.getString("table_name");

                System.out.println("table: " + tableName);
                getColumnSt.setString(1, tableName);

                System.out.println("SELECT * FROM all_tab_cols WHERE table_name = " + tableName + "");
                getColumnRs = getColumnSt.executeQuery();
                String createTableSQL = "create table if not exists " + tableName + " ( ";
                int index = 0;
                ArrayList<String> Columns = new ArrayList<>();
                while (getColumnRs.next()){
                    String columnName = getColumnRs.getString("column_name");
                    Columns.add(columnName);
                    System.out.println("column: " + columnName);
                    if (index == 0) {
                        createTableSQL += columnName + " string";
                    } else {
                        createTableSQL += " , " + columnName + " string";
                    }
                    index++;
                }
                createTableSQL += ")";
                System.out.println(createTableSQL);
                statement.executeUpdate(createTableSQL);

                getKeySt.setString(1, tableName);
                getKeyRs = getKeySt.executeQuery();
                keyName = "1";
                while (getKeyRs.next()) {
                    keyName = getKeyRs.getString("column_name");
                }

                Tales.add(new Table(tableName, keyName, Columns));

            }

            getTableCon.close();
            getColumnCon.close();
            getKeyCon.close();
            System.out.println("All  table created...");
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());

        }
      dumpData();

    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps using `dataSt.setFetchSize(incrementRecord)` is still too many records. Try starting from smaller increments and work up.  Also, not sure of the supported tooling, but it would probably be faster to not use java, e.g., export then import without a process (java) in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to issue/excute commit on SQLite  after inserting every batch of records.
2. And try to come-up with suitable batch size (may be 100).